Laravel 11 Sanctum requests from React throw 400 errors
Following Laravel 11 documentation, I added Sanctum using the following command:
php artisan install:api
I updated the user model to the following:
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;
.....

cors.config
return [
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];

sanctum.php
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
return [

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),
    'guard' => ['web'],
    'expiration' => null,
    'token_prefix' => env('SANCTUM_TOKEN_PREFIX', ''),
    'middleware' => [
        'authenticate_session' => Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        'validate_csrf_token' => Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidateCsrfToken::class,
    ],
];

the api.php route looks like this
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\CourseController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\AuthController;

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::get('courses', [CourseController::class, 'list']);//->middleware('auth:sanctum');

Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);
Route::post('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);

I won't paste the entire AuthController logic to not bloat the question, but the login looks as follows:
public function login(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

            return response()->json([
                'status' => false,
                'message' => "Credentials don't match.",
            ], 401);
        }

        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => true,
            'message' => 'user logged in successfully',
            'token' => $user->createToken("API TOKEN")->plainTextToken
        ], 200);

    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => $e->getMessage(),
        ]);
    }
}

When I go to postman, I am able to login.
How my React login page throws a 419 error when I attempt to login:
Below is what I have in React:
App.js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from './AuthContext';
import Login from './pages/login';
import Register from './pages/register';
import Courses from './pages/courses';
import Home from './pages/home';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <AuthProvider>
            <Navigation />
            <Router>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                    <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
                    <Route path="/courses" element={<Courses />} />
                </Routes>
            </Router>
        </AuthProvider>
    );
};

export default App;

src/AuthContext.js
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { fetchUser } from './authService';

const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const loadUser = async () => {
            try {
                const userData = await fetchUser();
                setUser(userData);
            } catch (error) {
                setUser(null);
            }
        };

        loadUser();
    }, []);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
};

src/authService
import axiosInstance from './axios';
import { getCsrfCookie } from './csrf';

export const login = async (email, password) => {
    await getCsrfCookie();
    const response = await axiosInstance.post('/api/login', { email, password });
    return response.data;
};

export const register = async (formData) => {
    const response = await axiosInstance(`/api/register`, formData);
    return response.data;
};

export const logout = async () => {
    const response = await axiosInstance.post('/api/logout');
    return response.data;
};

export const fetchUser = async () => {
    await getCsrfCookie();
    const response = await axiosInstance.get('/api/user');
    return response.data;
};

The axios setup in src/axios.js is as follows:
import axios from 'axios';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000',
    withCredentials: true,
});

export default axiosInstance;

src/csrf.js
import axiosInstance from './axios';

export const getCsrfCookie = async () => {
    await axiosInstance.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie');
};

At this point, if I refresh the page I see the following error in the console:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Meaning that something is wrong regarding the /sanctum/csrf-cookie route.
The login page (src/pages/login.js) looks as follows:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth } from '../AuthContext';
import { login } from '../authService';

const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const { setUser } = useAuth();

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const user = await login(email, password);
            setUser(user);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Login failed', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-100">
            <div className="bg-white p-8 rounded shadow-md w-full max-w-md">
                <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-6 text-center">Login</h2>
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="space-y-6">
                    <div>
                        <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Email</label>
                        <input
                            type="email"
                            value={email}
                            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                            required
                            className="mt-1 block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label className="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Password</label>
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            value={password}
                            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                            required
                            className="mt-1 block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <button
                            type="submit"
                            className="w-full flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm font-medium text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500"
                        >
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Login;

When I go to postman, I am able to login.
How my React login page throws a 419 error when I attempt to login.
My Laravel is sitting on http://127.0.0.1:8000/
The React site is on http://localhost:3000, which in theory was cleared by the sanctum configuration.
How can I allow my React application to authenticate, and ensure that I am able to make requests to other endpoints protected by the Sanctum middleware?
I have dug quite a bit and the answers found so far seem to be outdated :(

did you forgot to request for csrf_token ? axios.get('http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie') ?

Definitely not @xenooooo. I edited my question in order to give full context.

how about php artisan optimize:clear ?. or remove the session values in http://127.0.0.1:8000
